# Java :Questions on clone method

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, clone

I got these asked in an interview.

> 1. Do we need to take care of clone method in a concurrent environment ? Can we synchronize the clone method ?
> 2. Does it make any sense to use clone method in singleton classes ?

I did not have convincing answers for this during the interview.

Comment: Don't worry about it. These are horrible interview questions, so you probably didn't want to work there anyway.

Comment: Do you know what singleton means?

Comment: Where is this? Can I work there?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Why do you want to work there ? :)

Comment: @user2434 I want a job working with people that understand concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably yes 99.99% of the times but you just have to think at clone like any other methods of your class and synchronize it if necessary depending on your specific context. There is nothing wrong in synchronizing a method that is not synchronized in its Base class. On the other hand, **not synchronizing a method while overriding a synchronized one is probably a mistake** even if the code compiles fine and no warnings are issued...
2. A convincing answer would probably be NO with a couple of words on the singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are cloning an object which is subject to change in other threads, then you will probably need to acquire some sort of [read] lock just as if you were doing any other operation on it. Theoretically you would need a lock on the new object if it could ever be subject to unsafe publication (I suggest not publishing mutable object unsafely!).
2. It wouldn't be a singleton if you could make another instance of it (there is the monostate antipattern which is like the singleton antipattern, only worse and can involve multiple objects for no clear purpose). I guess if you were subclassing some class that implemented `Cloneable` you want to override `clone` and either throw `CloneNotSupportedException` is possible or otherwise return `this`.